# Log to ELK from Nomad without using container technology

Tags: devops, nomad, hashicorp

We are using Hashicorp Nomad to run microservices on Windows. We experienced that allocations come and go, but we would like to have centralized logging solution (ideally ELK) for all logs from all jobs and tasks from multiple environments. It is quite simple to do it with dockerized environments, but how can I do it if I run `raw_exec` tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing specific to containers for log shipping other than the output driver. If containers write their logs to volumes, which Nomad can be configured to do, then the answer is the same.

Assuming your `raw_exec` jobs write logs into the local filesystem, then you need a log shipper product such as Filebeat or Fluentd to watch those paths, then push that data to Elastic / Logstash.

Comment: Thanks, it a bit late, but thats exactly what we did